# How to use Vuepress or Vitepress into an existing Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vuepress, vitepress

Is there a way of integrate inside a Vue project a Vitepress or Vuepress project?. Is there a way to create system documentation like that created by Vuepress or Vitepress that can be accessed from within the system?

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about. Their output are static files that are supposed to to be served by web server. What's the relation to this vue project?

Comment: I would like to use it inside my project, not deploy it separately. And the route /docs its imposible to reach because the router throws me a 404. I tried build it and reference the html inside my template but it didn't work.

Comment: It's solved from the back end, not front. You can deploy them to the same server but they are different apps and should be built separately. What didn't work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

VitePress can be used on its own, or be installed into an existing project.

In both cases, you can install it with :

```bash
npm add -D vitepress
```

If you are installing VitePress in an existing project alongside other source code, it is recommended to scaffold the site in a nested directory (e.g. ./docs) so that it is separate from the rest of the project.

```bash
.
├─ docs
│  ├─ .vitepress
│  │  └─ config.js
│  ├─ api-examples.md
│  ├─ markdown-examples.md
│  └─ index.md
└─ package.json
```

ref.

1. https://vitepress.dev/guide/getting-started#installation
2. https://vitepress.dev/guide/getting-started#file-structure